# document.GetElementById("main").innerHTML = "testing" is reverting, not changing permanently

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Below is my java.html code where i am inserting `<a href='' onclick='load_des()'><li><p>$row[Title]</p></li></a>` element in to the div element whose id is "main" which is echoing from another php script to the ajax as response as you can see in the below code. insertion is successful, but when i click the element the load_des() function is called, showing the "testing" word for a blink and again showing back the link. But my intention is to show up the "testing" word permanently, don't know something happening in AJAX code?
[click this link, then click Java option under domains, you will find the Link named Test, this is the link i am explaining above](http://algoranker.com/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function on_load(){
   var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

      }
   }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","load_ques.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }

 function load_des(){
     document.getElementById("main").innerHTML="testing";
      return false;
 }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="on_load()">
 <div id="main">

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `load_des()` anywhere.

Comment: i am calling it in the element <a href='' onclick='load_des()'><li><p>$row[Title]</p></li></a> which is inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, change `load_des()` to `return load_des()`. This will prevent the current page from loading again.

```
<a href='' onclick='return load_des()'><li><p>$row[Title]</p></li></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You click the link. The onclick attribute triggers. The JavaScript runs. The `href` attribute of the link is followed. A new page is loaded (throwing away the DOM of the previous page).

You need to stop the default behaviour of the link.

If you're using intrinsic event attributes like `onclick` you need to `return false;` at the end.

```
onclick="load_des(); return false;"
```